# Is there a more simpler way to do this? Such as maybe using a ForLoop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 10 InputFields. I wish to have its data saved when the user or player exits the app or switches Scenes. I proceeded with setting the data or text of the InputFields to a string that gets stored via PlayerPrefs via SetString and on Start the script sets the InputFields to the string of the PlayerPrefs via GetString. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Saving : MonoBehaviour
{
public TMP_InputField dumbellPressData;
string dumbellPressString;

public TMP_InputField inclineDumbellPressData;
string inclineDumbellPressString;

public TMP_InputField peckDeckData;
string peckDeckString;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    dumbellPressString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("DumbellPressData");
    dumbellPressData.text = dumbellPressString;

    inclineDumbellPressString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("InclineDumbellPressData");
    inclineDumbellPressData.text = inclineDumbellPressString;

    peckDeckString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PeckDeckData");
    peckDeckData.text = peckDeckString;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    dumbellPressString = dumbellPressData.text;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("DumbellPressData", dumbellPressString);

    inclineDumbellPressString = inclineDumbellPressData.text;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("InclineDumbellPressData", inclineDumbellPressString);

    peckDeckString = peckDeckData.text;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PeckDeckData", peckDeckString);
}
```

}

My question is whether there is an easier way or a more simplified way to go abouts coding this. In the code above I merely did them for 3 InputFields and I still have 7 more to fill out. Is copy pasting them the only way to go abouts this? Maybe if I made an array of InputFields and an array of Strings to assign the Inputfields to before storing it via PlayerPrefs?

Comment: You could use an array but that might make it less convenient to set up in the inspector. You definitely should not be saving the data every frame if it has not changed. Those calls to PlayerPrefs aren't free.

Comment: Your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Don't save and set string every frame. Set strings when they change and save when on specific events like when you exit app.

Comment: @MickyD The question is not off-topic; it's asking if there is a way to achieve the same output without having to write a new variable assignment for each input field.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any need to actually create fields in your code. A dictionary should suffice.

Try this:

```
public class Saving : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<string, TMP_InputField> _data = new Dictionary<string, TMP_InputField>()
    {
        { "DumbellPressData", new TMP_InputField() },
        { "InclineDumbellPressData", new TMP_InputField() },
        { "PeckDeckData", new TMP_InputField() },
    };

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _data)
            kvp.Value.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString(kvp.Key);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _data)
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.text);
    }
}
```

Or perhaps this:

```
public class Saving : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string[] _fields =
    {
        "DumbellPressData", "InclineDumbellPressData", "PeckDeckData"
    };
    
    private Dictionary<string, TMP_InputField> _inputs;
    
    public Saving()
    {
        _inputs = _fields.ToDictionary(x => x, _ => new TMP_InputField());
    }

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var field in _fields)
            _inputs[field].text = PlayerPrefs.GetString(field);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (var field in _fields)
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(field, _inputs[field].text);
    }
}
```

The second way is my preferred way. It introduces a bit more code, but it makes configuration slightly easier and the executing code a little clearer to read.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm trying the second method that you proposed but I'm getting an error at the .ToDictionary line in this line of code: 

public Saving() { _inputs = _fields.ToDictionary(x => x, _ => new TMP_InputField()); }

It says that string[] does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary'.
Potential fixes stated to add the namespace using System.Linq but once I do that the new TMP_InputField in the same line of code becomes inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @RamKillnani - Can you put your code on dotnetfiddle to show me?